# Can I import classes from opencv-contrib-python through Buildozer for Face Recognition?

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, face-recognition, buildozer

I am still relatively new to Kivy Python programming. I am developing a kivy app for Android which uses face recognition with opencv and is compiled with buildozer. Many of the opencv extra classes such as (opencv.face....) are not included in the official opencv recipe for buildozer. How can I import them through buildozer(if possible)? I understand that creating recipes for Dlib is very difficult given its many external dependencies thus why I turned to opencv, which already has a recipe. Given opencv once had a face class before it got split into opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python I would have suspected that importing the Face class would be realistic. I am interested in extracting 68 facial points as this is central for my app. Any advice on this matter would be appreciated :)